# MySQL @local_variable not working for a row

Tags: mysql, sql

While doing R&D with the temporary variable, I came across an unusual behaviour of the database.
In order to fully explain my problem, I am sharing the table schema and its data.

These are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE category (
  categoryId INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  categoryName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  categoryFlag TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);

CREATE TABLE object (
  objectId INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  objectName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  objectFlag TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);

CREATE TABLE mapping(
  mapId INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  catId INT NOT NULL,
  objId INT NOT NULL,
  mapFlag TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  CONSTRAINT UC_mapping_cat_obj UNIQUE (catId,objId)
);
```

These are the records I am inserting into the table:

```
INSERT INTO category(categoryName) VALUES ('Beverage');
INSERT INTO category(categoryName) VALUES ('Dairy Product');
INSERT INTO category(categoryName) VALUES ('Desert');
INSERT INTO category(categoryName) VALUES ('Digestive Food');
INSERT INTO category(categoryName) VALUES ('Fruit');
INSERT INTO category(categoryName) VALUES ('Herb');
INSERT INTO category(categoryName) VALUES ('Preservative');
INSERT INTO category(categoryName) VALUES ('Spice');
INSERT INTO category(categoryName) VALUES ('Vegetable');

INSERT INTO object(objectName) VALUES ('Apple');
INSERT INTO object(objectName) VALUES ('Butter');
INSERT INTO object(objectName) VALUES ('Cabbage');
INSERT INTO object(objectName) VALUES ('Cake');
INSERT INTO object(objectName) VALUES ('Chili');
INSERT INTO object(objectName) VALUES ('Clove');
INSERT INTO object(objectName) VALUES ('Cinnamon');
INSERT INTO object(objectName) VALUES ('Coffee');
INSERT INTO object(objectName) VALUES ('Coriander');
INSERT INTO object(objectName) VALUES ('Curd');
INSERT INTO object(objectName) VALUES ('Curry Leaves');
INSERT INTO object(objectName) VALUES ('Green Tea');
INSERT INTO object(objectName) VALUES ('Holy Basil');
INSERT INTO object(objectName) VALUES ('Ice Cream');
INSERT INTO object(objectName) VALUES ('Indian Gooseberry');
INSERT INTO object(objectName) VALUES ('Lemon');
INSERT INTO object(objectName) VALUES ('Milk');
INSERT INTO object(objectName) VALUES ('Spinach');
INSERT INTO object(objectName) VALUES ('Turmeric');
INSERT INTO object(objectName) VALUES ('Tea');

INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Beverage' AND objectName = 'Coffee';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Beverage' AND objectName = 'Green Tea';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Beverage' AND objectName = 'Tea';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Dairy Product' AND objectName = 'Butter';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Dairy Product' AND objectName = 'Curd';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Dairy Product' AND objectName = 'Ice Cream';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Dairy Product' AND objectName = 'Milk';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Desert' AND objectName = 'Ice Cream';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Desert' AND objectName = 'Cake';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Digestive Food' AND objectName = 'Curd';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Digestive Food' AND objectName = 'Indian Gooseberry';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Digestive Food' AND objectName = 'Lemon';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Fruit' AND objectName = 'Apple';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Fruit' AND objectName = 'Indian Gooseberry';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Fruit' AND objectName = 'Lemon';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Herb' AND objectName = 'Clove';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Herb' AND objectName = 'Cinnamon';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Herb' AND objectName = 'Coriander';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Herb' AND objectName = 'Holy Basil';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Herb' AND objectName = 'Turmeric';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Preservative' AND objectName = 'Clove';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Preservative' AND objectName = 'Cinnamon';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Preservative' AND objectName = 'Lemon';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Spice' AND objectName = 'Chili';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Spice' AND objectName = 'Cinnamon';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Spice' AND objectName = 'Curry Leaves';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Spice' AND objectName = 'Holy Basil';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Spice' AND objectName = 'Turmeric';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Vegetable' AND objectName = 'Cabbage';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Vegetable' AND objectName = 'Coriander';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Vegetable' AND objectName = 'Spinach';
```

The query that joins mapping table with category and object table:

```
SET @catName='';
SELECT
  CASE WHEN @catName=categoryName THEN '' ELSE @catName:=categoryName END AS catName, 
  objectName
FROM mapping
INNER JOIN category ON catId = categoryId
INNER JOIN object ON objId = objectId
ORDER BY categoryName, objectName ;
```

[Screenshot highlighting the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdRK3.png)

As you can see in the image, I have highlighted the row which is supposed to show the value 'Preservative' but shows 'Spice' and the row just below must show value 'Spice' but shows 'Preservative' instead.

I cannot figure out the reason for this unusual behavior. I tried to change the order of inner join table, but it did not work. Joining with 'category' table or 'object' table does not seem to work either.

**I am able to come up with sequence that can reproduce this issue.**

```
-- Insert in -> category
INSERT INTO category(categoryName) VALUES ('Digestive Food');
INSERT INTO category(categoryName) VALUES ('Beverage');
INSERT INTO category(categoryName) VALUES ('Fruit');
INSERT INTO category(categoryName) VALUES ('Desert');
INSERT INTO category(categoryName) VALUES ('Vegetable');
INSERT INTO category(categoryName) VALUES ('Preservative');
INSERT INTO category(categoryName) VALUES ('Dairy Product');
INSERT INTO category(categoryName) VALUES ('Spice');
INSERT INTO category(categoryName) VALUES ('Herb');



-- Insert in -> object
INSERT INTO object(objectName) VALUES ('Cake');
INSERT INTO object(objectName) VALUES ('Turmeric');
INSERT INTO object(objectName) VALUES ('Chili');
INSERT INTO object(objectName) VALUES ('Tea');
INSERT INTO object(objectName) VALUES ('Coriander');
INSERT INTO object(objectName) VALUES ('Apple');
INSERT INTO object(objectName) VALUES ('Butter');
INSERT INTO object(objectName) VALUES ('Cabbage');
INSERT INTO object(objectName) VALUES ('Spinach');
INSERT INTO object(objectName) VALUES ('Ice Cream');
INSERT INTO object(objectName) VALUES ('Clove');
INSERT INTO object(objectName) VALUES ('Milk');
INSERT INTO object(objectName) VALUES ('Coffee');
INSERT INTO object(objectName) VALUES ('Green Tea');
INSERT INTO object(objectName) VALUES ('Holy Basil');
INSERT INTO object(objectName) VALUES ('Cinnamon');
INSERT INTO object(objectName) VALUES ('Curry Leaves');
INSERT INTO object(objectName) VALUES ('Lemon');
INSERT INTO object(objectName) VALUES ('Curd');
INSERT INTO object(objectName) VALUES ('Indian Gooseberry');



-- Insert in -> mapping
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Dairy Product' AND objectName = 'Butter';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Spice' AND objectName = 'Holy Basil';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Herb' AND objectName = 'Cinnamon';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Herb' AND objectName = 'Coriander';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Dairy Product' AND objectName = 'Ice Cream';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Desert' AND objectName = 'Cake';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Desert' AND objectName = 'Ice Cream';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Fruit' AND objectName = 'Lemon';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Spice' AND objectName = 'Cinnamon';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Digestive Food' AND objectName = 'Curd';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Dairy Product' AND objectName = 'Curd';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Vegetable' AND objectName = 'Spinach';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Herb' AND objectName = 'Holy Basil';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Spice' AND objectName = 'Curry Leaves';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Digestive Food' AND objectName = 'Indian Gooseberry';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Digestive Food' AND objectName = 'Lemon';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Fruit' AND objectName = 'Apple';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Fruit' AND objectName = 'Indian Gooseberry';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Preservative' AND objectName = 'Lemon';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Vegetable' AND objectName = 'Cabbage';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Herb' AND objectName = 'Clove';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Beverage' AND objectName = 'Tea';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Herb' AND objectName = 'Turmeric';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Vegetable' AND objectName = 'Coriander';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Preservative' AND objectName = 'Clove';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Dairy Product' AND objectName = 'Milk';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Beverage' AND objectName = 'Green Tea';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Spice' AND objectName = 'Chili';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Preservative' AND objectName = 'Cinnamon';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Spice' AND objectName = 'Turmeric';
INSERT INTO mapping (catId,objId) SELECT categoryId, objectId FROM category JOIN object WHERE categoryName = 'Beverage' AND objectName = 'Coffee';



-- Select Query
SET @catName='';
SELECT
  categoryName,
  CASE WHEN @catName=categoryName THEN '' ELSE @catName:=categoryName END AS catName, 
  objectName
FROM mapping
INNER JOIN category ON catId = categoryId
INNER JOIN object ON objId = objectId
ORDER BY categoryName, objectName ;
```

Comment: The image that I am trying to add is not adding due to some reason. Please try executing the query posted in the code section.

Comment: Able to add the image. See the image for clarity.

Comment: Your code seems to work in SQL Fiddle:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ddee8/1.

Comment: It works if the values are inserted in alphabetical order. If I shuffle the values while insertion, you may find the issue after executing the select query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL can be finicky with variables.  To be honest, I've seen this problem with `GROUP BY`, but not `ORDER BY`.  You can fix it by using a subquery:

```
SELECT categoryname,
       CASE WHEN @catName=categoryName THEN '' ELSE @catName:=categoryName END AS catName, 
       objectName
FROM (SELECT categoryname, objectname
      FROM mapping INNER JOIN
           category
           ON catId = categoryId INNER JOIN
           object
           ON objId = objectId
      ORDER BY categoryName, objectName
     ) co CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @catName = '') params;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ddee8/4) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: It is working.
I did explain for this query as well, even that shows decent stats.
Thank you.

Comment: @Vivek . . . I cannot figure out a reasonable scenario that would cause the behavior you observe.  I do think it is very strange.

Comment: Likewise here. Perhaps we can do a research on this one. Please tell me if you come to know the reason.